# Bridge configuration kvm and terraform

Tags: terraform, kvm

i am working with KVM to deploy VM.
i configure Bridge and the Network Source at the VM shows:

Bridge br0: Host device eth0
[image]

then i tried to deploy the same VM using terraform

but in the VM Network Source it shows:

[image]

it also change it to the vm i deploy manually (without terraform).

how can I retrieve it to the regular way?

i am afraid this change my network bridge configuration.

which cause the VM guest to not get IP by DHCP (as i configure in the tf file)

this is my tf file:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    libvirt  = {
      source = "dmacvicar/libvirt"
    }
  }
}

provider "libvirt" {
    uri = "qemu:///system"
}

resource "libvirt_volume" "centos7-qcow2" {
    name   = "centos7.qcow2"
    pool   = "default"
    source = "http://14.7.1.10_0.39637-disk1.qcow2"
    format = "qcow2"

}

data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = file("${path.module}/cloud_init.cfg")
}

data "template_file" "cloudinit_network" {
  template = file("${path.module}/network.cfg")
}

resource "libvirt_cloudinit_disk" "cloud_init" {
  name           = "commoninit.iso"
  user_data      = data.template_file.user_data.rendered
  network_config = data.template_file.cloudinit_network.rendered
}

resource "libvirt_network" "test_network" {
   name = "test_network"
   mode = "bridge"
   bridge = "br0"
#   addresses = ["10.100.86.5"]
   dhcp {
      enabled = true
   }
   
}

# Define KVM domain to create
resource "libvirt_domain" "gw" {
  name   = "gw"
  memory = "8192"
  vcpu   = 4
  
  cloudinit  = libvirt_cloudinit_disk.cloud_init.id
  qemu_agent = true
  
  network_interface {
#    network_name = "default"
    network_id = libvirt_network.test_network.id  
  }

  disk {
    volume_id = "${libvirt_volume.centos7-qcow2.id}"
  }

  console {
    type        = "pty"
    target_type = "serial"
    target_port = "0"
  }

  graphics {
    type         = "spice"
    listen_type  = "address"
    autoport     = true
  }
}

output "ips" {
  value = libvirt_domain.gw.*.network_interface.0.addresses
}
```

and this is my network.cfg:

```
version: 2
ethernets:
  eth0:
    dhcp4: true
    gateway4: 10.100.86.254
```

thanks for any help